# Adding Local JAR dependencies to Gradle for Travis CI

Tags: java, gradle, travis-ci

I am trying to have my project build with Travis CI. However, when it tries to compile my Java classes which rely on resources within jar files, the build fails. Is there a way to have these JAR files compile and prevent these errors?

Travis CI Console:

```
Unzipping /home/travis/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.12-all/2apkk7d25miauqf1pdjp1bm0uo/gradle-1.12-all.zip to /home/travis/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.12-all/2apkk7d25miauqf1pdjp1bm0uo
Set executable permissions for: /home/travis/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.12-all/2apkk7d25miauqf1pdjp1bm0uo/gradle-1.12/bin/gradle
:compileJava/home/travis/build/vontell/EasyAPI/src/resources/Constructors.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
import java.util.Base64;
                ^
  symbol:   class Base64
  location: package java.util
/home/travis/build/vontell/EasyAPI/src/resources/Constructors.java:12: error: package org.apache.http does not exist
import org.apache.http.Header;
                      ^
...... (these errors continue)
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.0'
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs = ['src']
    main.resources.srcDirs = ['src']
    test.java.srcDirs = ['tests/java']
    test.resources.srcDirs = ['tests/resources']
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

.travis.yml:

```
language: java
jdk: oraclejdk7
```

Comment: Base64 requires jdk8

Comment: Switching to jdk8 has fixed the Base64 issue. My problem with the Http classes and my .jar files from libs is still occurring however

Comment: Are those libs checked in? Generally its preferred to use external dependency coordinates, e.g. via maven central.

Comment: Adding them as dependencies from Maven Central worked for me. Thanks!